# NSFetchedResultsController corrupted sort after saving one of the listed objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a generic set of views/classes for CoreData browsing but am having trouble with the sort order for my fetched results controller after having saved a change to an attribute of one of the listed objects.

In `viewWillAppear:` of my table view controller I set up my fetched results controller as such:

```
- (void) setupFetchedResultsController {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName: self.entityToList];
    request.predicate = self.entitySelectionPredicate; // Typically nil
    request.sortDescriptors = self.entitySortDescriptorList;
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                 initWithFetchRequest: request 
                 managedObjectContext: self.contextForEntity
                 sectionNameKeyPath: self.keyPathForSections
                 cacheName: nil]; /* Not chacheing */
}
```

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for this tableview controller I push to a detail table view controller like this:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    id objectInCell = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    ManagedObjectDetailTableViewController *dvc = [[ManagedObjectDetailTableViewController alloc]
                    initWithStyle: UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    dvc.detailItem = objectInCell;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: dvc animated: YES];
}
```

The **ManagedObjectDetailTableViewController** has a row for each attribute and each relationship. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I push to a **ManagedObjectAttributeEditViewController** view controller if a row containing and attribute is selected:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    // Section 0 has the attributes for the 'detailItem' object alphabetically by name
    if( indexPath.section == 0 ) {
        ManagedObjectAttributeEditViewController *evc = [[ManagedObjectAttributeEditViewController alloc]
                    initWithNibName: @"ManagedObjectAttributeEditViewController" bundle: nil];
        evc.editedObject = self.detailItem;
        evc.delegate = self;
        // Figure out from the row which attribute was selected
        NSEntityDescription *entity = self.detailItem.entity;
        NSDictionary *attributes = entity.attributesByName;
        NSArray *keys = [attributes allKeys];
        keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
        NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        evc.editedFieldKey = key;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController: evc animated: YES];
    // The other sections are the relationships for the 'detailItem' object
    } else {
        // Code omitted as not relevant for the error.
    }
}
```

The **ManagedObjectAttributeEditViewController** has text fields, etc., to allow editing of the attribute's value. When it's save button is touched is executes:

```
- (IBAction) save {
    id valueFromView;
    NSAttributeType type = [self typeForEditedAttribute];
    switch( type ) {
    case NSDateAttributeType:
        valueFromView = self.datePicker.date;
        break;
    case NSStringAttributeType:
        if( [self.fieldKeyTester shouldUseTextViewForKey: self.editedFieldKey inEntity: self.editedObject.entity.name] ) {
            valueFromView = self.textView.text;
        } else {
            valueFromView = self.textField.text;
        }
        break;
    case NSInteger16AttributeType:
    case NSInteger32AttributeType:
    case NSInteger64AttributeType:
        valueFromView = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [self.textField.text integerValue]];
        break;
    case NSDecimalAttributeType:
    case NSDoubleAttributeType:
    case NSFloatAttributeType:
        valueFromView = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: [self.textField.text doubleValue]];
        break;
    case NSBooleanAttributeType:
        valueFromView = [NSNumber numberWithBool: self.switchControl.isOn];
        break;
    case NSObjectIDAttributeType:
    case NSTransformableAttributeType:
    case NSBinaryDataAttributeType:
    case NSUndefinedAttributeType:
        NSLog( @"Don't know how to handle attribute type: %d in %s", type, __func__ );
        break;
    default:
        NSLog( @"Unrecognized attribute type: %d in %s", type, __func__ );
        break;
    }
    [self.delegate managedObjectAttributeEditViewController: self
            didSaveValue: valueFromView forKey: self.editedFieldKey];
}
```

The **ManagedObjectDetailTableViewController** is set as the delegate and the `didSaveValue:forKey:` method is:

```
- (void) managedObjectAttributeEditViewController: (ManagedObjectAttributeEditViewController *) controller didSaveValue: (id) value forKey: (NSString *) key {
    if( value && key ) {
        [self.detailItem setValue: value forKey: key];
        NSError *error;
        if( ![self.detailItem.managedObjectContext save: &error] ) {
            // Update to handle the error appropriately.
            NSLog( @"Unresolved error doing save of attribute %@.\n%@", key, error.localizedDescription );
        } else {
            NSLog( @"-- successfully saved" );
        }
    } else {
        NSLog( @"Got a cancel from edit attribute" );
    }
    // OK, the attribute editing view controller has told us it is done, pop it
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

So, if I am starting with the list of objects for the entity, and they are correctly sorted. I touch a row and it pushes to the **ManagedObjectDetailTableViewController**. I touch an attribute row in that and it pushes to the **ManagedObjectAttributeEditViewController**. I change the value and touch **save**. This pops to the **ManagedObjectDetailTableViewController**, where everything looks fine. I then touch the back button to go back to the list of objects for the entity but now they are no longer sorted (they seem to always be in the same order but I don't recognize a pattern to the order).

If I count to 10 after doing the **save** and before touching the back button, the list is properly sorted.

If I comment out the `[self.detailItem.managedObjectContext save: &error]` method call in `didSaveValue:forKey:` then the list of objects for the entity remain correctly sorted but if I exit the application before an autosave has occurred I lose the changes.

This makes me think it has something to do with the `[self.detailItem.managedObjectContext save: &error]` having not completed and the fetched results controller (which is using the same NSManagedObjectContext) for some reason not being able to retrieve the data sorted.

The attribute whose value I am changing is not involved in the sort descriptors, so the order displayed should be the same before and after I revise the value. My database is quite large and it may take a few seconds to write it to disk. I am seeing the problem with iOS 5.1 in the simulator and on a device.

Has anyone ever experienced anything like this or have a suggestion?

Sorry this is so long winded and happy 4th of July for all those Stackoverflowers in the USA!

---

Revised **ManagedObjectDetailTableViewController** delegate method `didSaveValue:forKey:` method is:

```
- (void) managedObjectAttributeEditViewController: (ManagedObjectAttributeEditViewController *) controller
             didSaveValue: (id) value forKey: (NSString *) key {
    if( value && key ) {
        [self.detailItem setValue: value forKey: key];
        NSError *error;
        if( ![self.detailItem.managedObjectContext save: &error] ) {
            // Update to handle the error appropriately.
            NSLog( @"Unresolved error doing save of attribute %@.\n%@", key, error.localizedDescription );
        } else {
            NSLog( @"-- successfully saved" );
            if( [self.detailItem.managedObjectContext.parentContext.hasChanges] ) {
                if( ![self.detailItem.managedObjectContext.parentContext save: &error] ) {
                    NSLog( @"Unresolved error doing save of parent context for attribute %@.\n%@", key, error.localizedDescription );
                } else {
                    NSLog( @"-- successfully saved the parent context too!" );
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        NSLog( @"Got a cancel from edit attribute" );
    }
    // OK, the attribute editing view controller has told us it is done, pop it
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

I now understand that this double save is necessary for the changes to make it to the permanent store with the latest iOS since with a parent context the save only goes up one level. I don't understand why not having the save propagated to the permanent store should scramble the sort order. Maybe there is some other bug somewhere in my code that this is masking or maybe it is just the way it works...

Answer (score 1):

OK, based on your edits which include the new stack traces:

You're using UIManagedDocument to manage your core data stack. This means the first save is probably from the UIDocument's main thread context and the second is from its background context. Can you confirm that you're using objects from the UIManagedDocument's managedObjectContext context (as opposed to some other context you're making yourself)?

Another thing. Can you confirm that `entitySortDescriptorList` is not becoming nil somehow in you `setupFetchedResultsController` method?

Finally, as other diagnostics:

- Try calling `save:` from your top level view controller and see what happens.
- What happens if you make a delegate for your NSFetchedResultsController? Do you get change notifications? Do they seem reasonable?

Comment: The save is on the main thread but I have only changed one attribute of one managed object so it should not be saving the whole database, just one record, and that should save very quickly. `reloadData` is triggered when I reset the `fetchedResultsController`. I will try setting the observers and see what I can learn. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I was confused trying to listen for the notifications because of different view controllers loading and unloading so I added a `willSave` to my managed object subclass. Interestingly it gets called immediately after my `[self.detailItem.managedObjectContext save: &error]` call, as expected, but then about 10-seconds later gets called again without me doing anything. If I kill the program before the second one then the changes are not present in the database the next time I run the application!

Comment: Try looking at or posting the stack trace of the second notification so you can figure out where it's coming from.

Comment: OK, looking at the stack trace has too many things I don't recognize. I  will append them to the question above. I also looked at the `hasChanges` property of the `NSManagedObject`, the `NSManagedObjectContext` that contains it, and the `parentContext` these go from +, +, - to -, -, + (+ == true/hasChanges and - == false/!hasChanges) around my **save** so I am suspicious that the late save that I am seeing is from the `parentContext`

Comment: I agree; the latter save is likely from the parent context. I've made some edits with new suggestions.

Comment: Yes I am using a `UIManagedDocument` to manage my core data stack. The save should be in the main thread (I pass an NSManagedObject for the selected row supplied by `[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath]` then use the `save` method through that object's `NSManagedObjectContext` property. Yes, I can confirm that the `entitySortDescriptorList` is not becoming nil. That was my first suspicion but I put `NSLog()s` to print it every time and it never changed.

Comment: I tried putting a save at the start of `viewWillAppear` like this: `[[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] save: &error]` and it succeeded but the table rows are still scrambled.

Comment: The `NSFetchedResultsController` already had a delegate and all the correct notifications seemed to happen.

Comment: Since there was that delayed save from the `parentContext` I decided why not try saving it too? So now I save the context and if successful I save the context.parentContext. This fixes the problem but why should I have to do two saves?

Comment: Yeah, that's very weird. It's like fetching in the child context doesn't sort until the parent context is saved. Like in-memory (as opposed to using-sql) fetches is broken?

Comment: Thanks for all your help... the problem is gone but I am not sure it is really fixed or still exists somewhere deep in my code and is just masked by the 'double save'.